# How can I get emacs to show line numbers when the 'text-mode-hook appears not to be working?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am trying to use setnu.el to give me line numbers in emacs, which as you might imagine I want in pretty much every mode. It seemed like the preffered way of doing this in Emacs is to use

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-setnu-mode)
```

but this isn't working for me. Using

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'turn-on-setnu-mode)
```

works just fine when I am editing emacs lisp files, but I want line numbers in all my text viewing and don't want to have a special case for each kind of file in my init.d file. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "text-mode hook isn't working"?  Are you assuming that your programming modes are derived from `text-mode`?  They're not.  Why would you need a hook anyway, if you want it enabled globally?

Answer (score 5):

Linum seems to be distributed with emacs >=22.

Try:

```
(require 'linum)
```

Then toggle the display of line numbers with

```
M-x linum-mode
```

http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/linum/linum.html

Comment: This didn't work for me, I have emacs 22 but it says it cant find linum

Comment: Did you try to download the .el script from the link?  http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/linum/linum.el